# PHP Sessions or cookies, which is better?

Tags: php, html

I was reading about sessions and cookies in php and I don't know which one is better to use

can anyone explain the difference ?
thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a good question, you could find good answers for this on the internet and also here on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that cookies live on the **client** and session lives on the **server**.

Cookies can be set to a long lifespan, which means that data stored in a cookie can be stored for months if not years.

Sessions are stored on the server, which means clients do not have access to the information you store about them - this is particularly important if you store shopping baskets or other information you do not want you visitors to be able to edit by hand by hacking their cookies.